# npx package installation failure due to socket time out how do if fix this

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, ethereum

C:\Users\norine>npx create-react-app react-dapp

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\norine\react-dapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/code-frame/-/code-frame-7.10.4.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\norine\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-06-05T05_33_42_735Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react-dapp/ from C:\Users\norine
Done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

Or

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

Install yarn globally with using npm

```
npm i -g yarn@latest
```

then try,

```
yarn create react-app app_name
```